# Highlighting a text excluding its presence within the span tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, highlight

I want to highlight the text when it is searched.
But I'm unable to write a proper regex.
Basically, my search term is present within the `<span>` tags as a class name and also the text is there outside the `<span>` tags.

On search of that term it is highlighting the text within the `<span>` also due to which the span tags opens up and breaks.
So I wrote this regex -> `var searchRegExp = new RegExp('(' + searchTerm + ') +"(?!([^<]+)?>)"', 'gi');`
Now the problem is that if my search term is having `>` ,this also is not highlighted when searched.
Help me with the Regex.

This is my Regex which is not working properly ->
`var searchRegExp = new RegExp('(' + searchTerm + ') +"(?!([^<]+)?>)"', 'gi');`

Comment: Where does the text come from that you're searching in? Is it in a HTML document in which your JavaScript is also running? If so, just use the DOM tree and then you won't have to worry about searching in tags.

Comment: So you basically want to re-implement what my browser offers via [crtl]+[f] already? What for …?

Comment: @MrLister , the search term is passed into the javascript to highlight and that search term traverse over the texts to find the search term and highlights that term if present.

Now I want the search term to exclude those sections of the  texts where the search term is present within the <span> tags and don't want to highlight those.

for that i wrote the Regex, but that regex is excluding the search term if that search term is present with the `>` in the texts where i want to highlight.